# How to set header to HttpHeaders in angular 5

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, angular5

I'm trying to figure out how to handle headers on HttpHeaders to use them for http requests via HttpClient.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('foo', 'bar');
headers.set('foo', 'bar');

console.log(headers.get('foo')) // null
```

it works only this way:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('foo', 'bar');
console.log(headers.get('foo')) // bar
```

Is there a special way to add headers? Or it is a bug?

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19044)

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const url = `https://sampleapi.com`;

@Injectable()
export class BasicService {
  private _headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getWithHeader(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = this._headers.append('foo', 'Bar');
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, { headers : headers });
  }
}
```

This starts with a private variable that holds the initial set of headers, using `set`. Then uses `append` to add an additional headers before making the Http call.

Note that `append` returns an HttpHeaders object, which is why I assign the output to a const. Just running `append` by itself, thinking that the existing `_headers` will be changed, will not give you the results you might expect. I did confirm that HttpHeaders are immutable.

EDIT: From the [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) docs: *Immutable set of Http headers, with lazy parsing.*

Comment: can we use headers.append in loop to add multiple values from json array