# Error upload to imgur (malformed auth header)

Tags: angular, imgur

I'm trying to use Imgur to upload some images in an angular web app, but keep getting **"Malformed auth header"**, does anybody know how to fix this error?

```html
async uploadImage(imageFile: File, infoObject: {}, categoryId) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);

        const header = new HttpHeaders(`Authorization: Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxx`);
        const imageData = await this.http.post(this.url, formData, {headers: header}).toPromise();
        this.imageLink = imageData['data'].link;

        const newImageObject: ImageInfo = {
          title: infoObject['title'],
          description: infoObject['description'],
          link: this.imageLink
        };
        this.images.unshift(newImageObject);
        this.updateCategoryImgIconPath(categoryId, this.imageLink).subscribe(data => window.location.reload());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904687/how-to-set-header-to-httpheaders-in-angular-5) to set HttpHeaders in Angular is like this:

```js
const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxx');
```