# Spring boot server return error for Angular 8 -custom HTTP header :MissingRequestHeaderException

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to add custom http header to my GET request
I'm using Angular 8 and spring boot for my application.
I can't get my head around of how to send this header in the right way, and why does the server dosen't get it..
 here is my attempt to do so:(client)

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("realityId", "0");

export class FileService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
getFileList(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`,{headers});
}
```

and the relevant server code from my controller:

```
public HttpEntity<FlowersList> getFlowersFromFlowers(@RequestHeader String realityId, 
@RequestParam("mName") String mName)
```

no matter what I'm trying to do I keep on getting the error:

```
[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Missing request header 'realityId' for 
method parameter of type String]
```

I've been trying to do it like this:

```
 httpOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'realityId': '0' })
  };
```

But nothing, I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-http-client/) and [this one](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings/), and trying to get help from this [stuck overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular)

Any help would be appreciate

P.s whatever solutions I find for angular 2 and 4 does not work for me..

edit: I also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904687/how-to-set-header-to-httpheaders-in-angular-5) , tried the exact same thing, and still keep getting this error..I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you see the header being sent in the network debugger?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set("realityId", "0");
```

the instance of the first headers is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the headers. Try it like this:

```
return this.http.get('url', {
  headers: yourHeaders
});
```

You have to pass the headers to the headers property

Comment: the {headers} syntax is perfectly valid since es6.